# Orchard widget names all empty when retrieving by layer

Tags: widget, orchardcms

```
var globalWidgets = _widgetService.GetWidgets(GlobalLayer.Id);
```

The above code is used to retrieve a list of widgets all added to my `GlobalLayer`. This successfully retrieves the 3 widgets I'd expect, along with `Position`, `Title` and `Zone` that I need for each. However, `Name` is empty for all widgets in `globalWidgets`.

I can confirm when creating the widgets on the `GlobalLayer` I passed in the name like so:

```
_widgetService.CreateWidget(GlobalLayer.Id, "DansWidget", "Dans Widget", "1", "DansZone");
```

So where have the names gone?

Answer (score 0):

I'd still like somebody to tell me why this is the case, but I've just discovered I can access the name like so:

```
var name = globalWidgets.First().TypeDefinition.Name;
```